# One-hot representation of a matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

What is the easiest/smartest way of going from a matrix of values to one hot representation of the same thing in 3d tensor? For example if the matrix is the index after argmax in a tensor like:

```
indices=numpy.argmax(mytensor,axis=2)
```

Where tensor is 3D [x,y,z] and indices will naturally be [x,y]. Now you want to go to a 3D [x,y,z] tensor that has 1s in the place of maxes in axis=2 and 0 in any other place.

P.S. I know the answer for vector to 1-hot matrix, but this is matrix to 1-hot tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the perfect setups to use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
indices[...,None] == np.arange(mytensor.shape[-1])
```

If you need in ints of `0s` and `1s`, append with `.astype(int)`

Comment: Cool answer! Out of curiosity anything that doesn't use arange?

Comment: @A2B Use `range` instead of `np.arange`? :) What's wrong with using `arange`? Are you looking for a built-in to create such a one-hot array? If so, there's isn't any.

Comment: @A2B We can intialize the 3D output array of zeros and then assign values of 1s into it based on `indices`. Would that be *elegant* enough for you? Oh wait, we would still need `np.arange` for that indexing part.

Comment: You can't just say same_shape_zero_tensor[matrix]=1. So there has to be another function to turn [i,j]->m into [i,j,m], which is resolving where in the matrix value m resides.

Comment: @A2B Well `indices` are the last axis indices. We just need to generate the indices corresponding to first two axes. For the same, it has to involve range creation explicitly or implicitly.